# Windows Store application + Simulation in MSVS 2013

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-store-apps, credentials

First, sorry for my English it`s not my native language.
Second I start to learn [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn631757.aspx) for create Windows Store application.

In the end of Part 3 we were invited to use Visual Studio Simulator. But when I run it I take an error:

> Windows Simulator needs your credentials. Please lock this computerm then unlock it using your current password and run the Windows Simulator again. To lock your computer, press CTRL-ALT-DEL and the press Enter

I found some reference http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2892596, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2898148 but I didn`t do updates from 8 to 8.1 and I have MSVS2013.

My computer is placed in domain and I use smartcard authentication. Windows 8.1 + Visual Studio 2013 Update 3.

Comment: Well, don't use the smartcard.

Comment: @HansPassant, you think that is cause of my problem? But it's very strange I use all company resources without additional authentication and unfortunately I must use this way of authentication. Mb I don't know about some simulator or visual studio or windows settings that can help me?

Comment: @HansPassant, I created virtual machine without smartcard authentication and all works fine.