# Cannot start simulator for Windows 8 Universal App on Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10

I have an error while trying to start universal App for Windows 8 in simulator.
Using Windows 10 build 10130 with all latest updates and Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition:

> Windows Simulator needs your credentials. Please lock this computer
>   then unlock it using your current password and run the Windows
>   Simulator again. To lock your computer, press CTRL-ALT-DEL and the
>   press Enter

By searching the Stackexchange I found a link to similar problem, but with previous version of VS/Windows and in different environment. [Windows Store application + Simulation in MSVS 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26884868/windows-store-application-simulation-in-msvs-2013)
MS solution for Windows 8 is also not applicable in this case...
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2892596
Maybe anyone is familiar with a problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For some reason is doesn't work if you login using your pin instead of your password. It worked for me when I restarted and used my password instead of pin. I had to run the simulator 3 times before it started up correctly, but it did work.

Comment: I don't use the PIN in general and I tried to run Simulator about 10 times, but it just gives me OPs error-message. Any idea whats going on?

Comment: Sorry, no. I think it's a bug in the simulator. This is just a workaround.

Comment: A bug that doesn't exist in Windows 10 anymore if you ask MS... Thank you anyway!

Comment: Do you have a link to where this is stated?

Comment: Everything about this problem in the KB is Win8, so it doesn't exist in Win10. Easy way to conclude...

Comment: You have to `LOGOUT` and `LOGIN` again with your **PASSWORD** instead of your **PIN**

Comment: This doesn't work, at least not on my Windows 10 installation.  How does Microsoft expect developers to work around all these show stopping bugs.

Answer (score 7):

I resolve this by logout (open Run and type logoff) and login using password (not PIN), lock computer and login not work

Comment: Confirmed that this solution works with Visual Studio 2015 Update 2, running on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem. I fixed it by restarting my pc. After the restart the simulator started on the second try (first try it crashed with a different error message)

Comment: I tried alot, but the Simulator and Mobile Emulator both are not running. How it can be fixed. plz

Comment: Restart pc, login with password (NOT PIN), try deploying your app to the simulator multiple times until it works

Comment: The simulator works but the Emulator is not running and give Two errors.

1.
Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during bootstrapping stage 'Connecting to the device '8BDF218D-FDBB-4A97-90F9-3AA33B559A92'.': 
DeviceException - App deployment failed. Please try again.

2.
Error : DEP6200 : Bootstrapping 'Mobile Emulator 10.0.10240.0 WVGA 4 inch 512MB' failed. Device cannot be found. App deployment failed. Please try again. TestUWP2

Answer (score 1):

Log out of your PC then use your password and not a PIN to log in.  Launch the simulator again and it will work.  This happens if you use your PIN to log in to your PC and locking and unlocking it with your password is not enough.  You must log out.

Answer (score 1):

It is solved with me by

1. Logout of your visual studio.
2. Second Close down visual studio
3. Restart Windows 10 Logging in **with password not PIN.**
4. Start visual studio.
5. Select & start your project.
6. Select Simulator and press green arrow and **wait** for about 60 sec. simulator will start .